# Is there a way to redefine the looks of buttons, tabs and other UI elements?

Tags: gui-construction

I am looking for pointers on how to redefine UI elements (in the FE as well as in a CDF document).

For example: the looks of a button, or of tab elements, and so on.

(I don't mean something like "changing the color of a (pressed or unpressed) button", I really mean the UI element appearance).

I have been looking around (web and here) and I didn't come up with an answer, nor with any kind of information...

Anyone has any pointers? Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: The appearance of the FrontEnd control elements is determined by operating system, not by the FrontEnd. So probably what you want is not possible.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah, I know it's OS-controlled, but I thought that maybe there's a way to redefine the looks of, eg, a button... :(

Comment: To bypass the OS look of UI elements you would need to build your own with building blocks like `EventHandler` (for buttons, tabview etc). Easy enough to do but beyond the scope of this question. For an example of a custom slider see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html.

Answer (score 1):

There are some options to `Button` that let you change the way a button looks. For example, `Appearance` and `BaseStyle`. Also, you can use a `Graphics` object as the button label, which will give you a lot of control over appearance. See [`Button`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Button.html) for more detail. In particular, look at Option > Neat Examples.